# Disable static content cache gwan

Tags: g-wan

Is there a way to disable G-wan's static content cache?
Is there Disable cache in general on G-wan?

I read the PDF located on gwan.com and noticed it has a micro cache feature which don't get me wrong is awesome. It's just not needed and counter productive in a dev environment. As the latest dynamic and static content is needed.

Regardless if I update the file or wait a minute or 2 it still seems to send the cached content. I even tried deleting the gzip dir hoping it would send me the latest version. It works on some files after I clear the file then save then paste back the code and save again.

Disabling cache is the best option for dev environment currently , if anyone could lend some knowledge it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tomek, If your application is RESTFUL then the cache never plays against you - maybe it's time to rethink the way you are mis-using the Web =)

Comment: Caching is disabled by default and can only be enabled manually, look at the `gwan/init.c` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hear you, caches are developer's enemy. :) Though, I'm not so sure if G-WAN implementation should change. If it's not the server, the browser will possibly take over and send it from the cache. Last month I even had a problem with the Flash Player caching a SWF causing all sorts of problems at work.

The simplest way to eliminate caches seems to be adding a (notorious) cache breaker string at the end of the URL. (well, that didn't work for the flash player case but that's another story.)

If you are using the latest 3.12.26 release there might be something else going wrong for your tests. G-Wan team will release a new stable version soon.

Comment: Ogla, only small files (a few kb) are cached. And G-Wan 3.12.26's code works perfectly when using another libc than glibc.

Comment: Caching is disabled by default, look at the `gwan/init.c` file.